# Sencha touch 2 - How to push a new view on click of a list item

Tags: sencha-touch-2

On the click of the NEWS , I want to push a view (card) . This is my controller . I am not using a navigation view .How to do that .

```
config:{
    routes:{
        'News/index': 'showNews',
    },
    refs : {
        main : 'mainpanel',
    },

    control : {
        'navigation': {
                   select : 'showLanding'
                 }
           }
     },

    showNews : function(){
                 this.getMain().add({
                   xtype: 'blogview'
                    });
                },
    showLanding :   function(list,record) {
                           switch(record.data.navLink){

                               case "NEWS" : {
                                              this.getMain().setActiveItem('blogview');                                        
                                              break;
                                            }
                                case "PHOTOS" : {

                                               this.getMain().push({                                             
                                                 xtype:'photoview',
                                              });
                                              break;
                                            }

                            }
                          }
```

I think we cannot give two or more items inside the navigation view . Can you plz help

Thanks in advance . :)

Comment: Is there any other way to push a new component without using navigation view

Comment: the above code is not working ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setActiveItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-setActiveItem) on a container which has a [card](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card) layout. Here is a simple example:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady:function(){
        var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [
                {
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Tap this to add a new view',
                            handler: function() {
                                container.setActiveItem({
                                    html: 'This is the new item.'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add(container);
    }
});
```

And you can add animations by specifying it in the [layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-layout) configuration:

```
layout: {
    type: 'card',
    animation: {
        type: 'slide',
        direction: 'left',
        duration: 1000
    }
}
```

With the complete being:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady:function(){
        var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            layout: {
                type: 'card',
                animation: {
                    type: 'slide',
                    direction: 'left',
                    duration: 1000
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Tap this to add a new view',
                            handler: function() {
                                container.setActiveItem({
                                    html: 'This is the new item.'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add(container);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . But I want to write this inside the controller. I want to take e ref of a view and push another view in that . How to do that .??

Comment: case "NEWS" : {
                                              this.getMain().setActiveItem('blogview');                                        
                                              break;
                                            }   This code is not working . Whats the ccorrect way ??

Answer (score 1):

1) Assign ID to the container whose view you would like to change.

2) In your controller get reference to the container by ID and call appropriate method to load the view.

For example, if you are using Navigation.View as your container, call push method to load desired view

```
Ext.ComponentManager.get('mynavigationview').push({
      title: 'Second',
      html: 'Second view!'
      });
```

Please note that your need to use 'Ext.ComponentManager.get' as 'Ext.get' doesn't work with Components.

Comment: Hii Thanks for the reply . That helped . what if I am not using the navigation view ?  . ext.ComponentManager.get('somePanel').add(someXtype);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from a controller I have. I removed the extra code on the onListItemTap method though.

Make sure your reference is actually working. If your 'mainPanel' is a navigation view, you can push new items in like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        mainPanel: 'main'
    },

    control: {
        "list": {
            itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
        }
    }
},

onListItemTap: function (dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {
    var myView = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    ...
    ...
    });

    this.getMainPanel().push(myView);
}

});
```

For your mainPanel, something like this should work:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'main',

    config: { }
});
```